# How do I add an object to an array

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I am trying to add an object to an array programatically. I have figured everything out, but I don't know how to add it to a certain user

```
func Save() {
   let user = PFUser.currentUser()
   user?.addObjectsFromArray([memberName.text!], forKey: "Family_Emails")

}
```

whenever I try to run it it does nothing

Comment: If you are adding "an object", you should use addObject, not addObjectsFromArray. Don't forget to call save on the user object

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects